# PHP: Remove line of code from template on a certain page

Tags: php

I have a site with a common template file. So all the pages have the same header and footer.

I want to remove a line of code from the header on a particular page.

- Is there a way I can say if the url is not `/user/page/****` than print this code?

Comment: Yes. There are some ways to do that.

Answer (score 1):

From your description,

You have pages in format `user/page/xxxxx`

So, you can directly explode the string with `/` and get the last element.

That is your current.

```
$currentPage = current(explode('/'), $yourURL);
if ($currentPage != 'noTemplatePageAddHere') {
  // Add the line you do not want to show on this page.
}
```